# sequencec vfs $x_n$ such that

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let be $x_n$ a sequence such that $0<x_0<1$ and
$$x_{n+1}=3x_n(1-x_n)$$
Find the limit of $x_n$

I obtained by induction that $0<x_n<1$
How should I continue.

Comment: What happens if you take $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ of both sides?

Comment: first prove that $x_n$ is convergent

Comment: Here is the solution. It's quite complicated https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4086271/195378

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some proof idea:

Let for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $x_n=\frac{2}{3}+\epsilon$, for some $-\frac{2}{3}<\epsilon<\frac{1}{3}$, assuming $0<x_n<1$ (note that we can always find such $n$).

Then we have

$x_{n+1}=3(\frac{2}{3}+\epsilon)(\frac{1}{3}-\epsilon)=\frac{2}{3}-\epsilon-3\epsilon^2$,  and

$x_{n+2}=3\left(\frac{2}{3}-(\epsilon+3\epsilon^2)\right)\left(\frac{1}{3}+(\epsilon+3\epsilon^2)\right)=\frac{2}{3}+\epsilon-18\epsilon^3-27\epsilon^4$

Hence, we have

$|x_{n}-\frac{2}{3}| = |\epsilon|$ and

$|x_{n+2}-\frac{2}{3}|= |\epsilon-18\epsilon^3-27\epsilon^4|$

Now, all we have to show is that $|\epsilon| > |\epsilon-18\epsilon^3-27\epsilon^4|$, so that we have $|x_{n+2}-\frac{2}{3}|<|x_{n}-\frac{2}{3}|$ and it can be extended to (by induction?) $|x_n-\frac{2}{3}|>|x_{n+2}-\frac{2}{3}|>|x_{n+4}-\frac{2}{3}|>\ldots$, and this non-negative monotonically decreasing sequence must be bounded from below by $0$, i.e., $\{x_n\}$ converges to $\frac{2}{3}$.

For example, let's start with $x_0=\frac{1}{6}$, then with the following `R` code simulating the sequence,

```
x <- 1/6 
xs <- c(x)
for (i in 1:10000) {
  x <- 3*x*(1-x)
  xs <- c(xs,x)
}
plot(1:length(xs), xs, typ='l', xlab='n', ylab='x_n')
```

we get the following plot:

[image]

```
abs(xs[1:100] - 2/3)
# [1] 0.50000000 0.25000000 0.06250000 0.07421875 0.05769348 0.06767909 0.05393772 0.06266555 0.05088463 0.05865237 0.04833207 0.05534004 0.04615248
# [14] 0.05254263 0.04426045 0.05013741 0.04259613 0.04803942 0.04111606 0.04618765 0.03978776 0.04453695 0.03858633 0.04305305 0.03749235 0.04170938
# [27] 0.03649036 0.04048500 0.03556790 0.03936312 0.03471476 0.03833010 0.03392251 0.03737472 0.03318411 0.03648767 0.03249362 0.03566112 0.03184598
# [40] 0.03488847 0.03123686 0.03416408 0.03066253 0.03348310 0.03011975 0.03284134 0.02960568 0.03223517 0.02911785 0.03166140 0.02865407 0.03111723
# [53] 0.02821239 0.03060020 0.02779109 0.03010812 0.02738862 0.02963903 0.02700362 0.02919120 0.02663482 0.02876306 0.02628112 0.02835322 0.02594150
# [66] 0.02796039 0.02561504 0.02758343 0.02530089 0.02722130 0.02499830 0.02687304 0.02470656 0.02653780 0.02442504 0.02621479 0.02415314 0.02590326
# [79] 0.02389033 0.02560257 0.02363610 0.02531209 0.02338998 0.02503126 0.02315157 0.02475955 0.02292045 0.02449649 0.02269625 0.02424161 0.02247865
# [92] 0.02399451 0.02226730 0.02375480 0.02206193 0.02352212 0.02186225 0.02329612 0.02166799 0.02307650

plot(1:100, abs(xs[1:100] - 2/3),type='l', xlab='n', ylab='|x_n - 2/3|')
```

[image]

Note from above that any subsequence formed with every alternate term of the above sequence $|x_n-\frac{2}{3}|$ is monotonically decreasing and thus converges to $0$.

Comment: Sorry but this solution doesn't work (or at least it haven't worked yet). The sequence $|x_n-\frac{2}{3}|$ converges, but what if it converges to $l > 0$?

Comment: No, you will have 2 values: $2/3 \pm l$, some of $x_n$ are closed to the first value, the others are closed to the second one. You can’t deduce (or at least haven’t yet deduced) that $l=0$. Besides, you can’t write the equality here.

Comment: I meant: if it converges to $l$, we can use the fact and let $\lim\limits_{n→∞}|x_n−\frac{2}{3}|=\lim\limits_{n→∞}|x_{n+1}−\frac{2}{3}|=l$ and then we shall have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=\frac{2}{3}\pm l$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}=3\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n(1-\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x_n) $ $\implies \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}=\frac{2}{3}+(\pm \frac{2}{3} \pm \frac{1}{3})l \pm 3l^2$ $\implies |x_{n+1}−\frac{2}{3}|=(\pm \frac{2}{3} \pm \frac{1}{3})l \pm 3l^2=l⟹l=0$, pretty tedious to write latex in comment

Comment: The problem is if there is two values $2/3 -l$ Then the sequences doesnt converge. So, you can’t write the limit.

Comment: By writing the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n$ from the begining, you assumed implicitly already that $l=0$

Comment: I see what you are saying, there should be a way to prove this, may be some other way this one can't be extended, since numerical simulations seem to show that the sequence converges at 2/3

Comment: Indeed the sequence converges, but this result haven’t been yet able to be deduced from your answer. A complete proof should be the one I put as comment of the question